# Cant insert the values of a List in separated rows of a csv

Tags: python

I can't manage to insert each value of a List in different rows/lines of the CSV. It goes to only one row.. What am I doing wrong? Thanl you.

```
formatted_lines = ['BR', 'BRQSB', 'BRQS', 'BRQSBWL9', 'CN', 'CNSHAWLT9001', 'CNS', 'DEA']

pathsave = 'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Py\\test.csv' 

import csv

with open(pathsave, "w", newline="") as myfile:
    wr = csv.writer(myfile, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)
    wr.writerow(formatted_lines)
```

What i want as output would be a csv with the format:

```
BR
BRQSB
BRQS
BRQSBWL9
...
```

Comment: `wr.writerows(...)`, not `wr.writerow(...)`

Comment: Doesnt work. With writerows the words are split like: "B","R" (first row) or "B","R","Q","S","B" (second row). Thanks.

Comment: Okay.  Try `wr.writerows([x] for x in formatted_lines)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify newline `\n` as [`delimiter`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/csv.html#csv.Dialect.delimiter)

```
formatted_lines = ['BR', 'BRQSB', 'BRQS', 'BRQSBWL9', 'CN', 'CNSHAWLT9001', 'CNS', 'DEA']

import csv

with open((pathsave, 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter='\n')
    writer.writerow(formatted_lines)
```

Because the newline character is platform dependent you can use [`os.linesep`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/os.html#os.linesep) instead.

```
import os
with open((pathsave, 'w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=os.linesep)
    writer.writerow(formatted_lines)
```

Comment: A small contribution, I would open the csv file as binary with 'wb' string (plataform encode), https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files

Comment: @FabioDuranVerdugo Why would you do that? OP is not writing a bin data.

Comment: @user3100115 Just for avoid the problem with encoding (\n on Unix, \r\n on Windows). As text say "the data is read and written in the form of bytes objects"

Comment: @FabioDuranVerdugo I would use `os.linesep` instead.

Comment: Well, is other way, "more elegantly"

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
formatted_lines = ['BR', 'BRQSB', 'BRQS', 'BRQSBWL9', 'CN', 'CNSHAWLT9001', 'CNS', 'DEA']

pathsave = 'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Py\\test.csv' 


with open(pathsave, "w", newline="") as myfile:
    myfile.write('\n'.join(formatted_lines))
```